# How to remove the unexpected tiny gap between adjacent DOM elements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When I scale the webpage, there will be **some slightly visible line** among these adjacent elements in `div.container`.

[image: unexpected gap line]

How does this happen and what can I do for that?

I am using `content-box` model to implement borders for complex shape. Also, I've applied grid layout to `div.container`, corresponding border lines to rectangles on each side, and a one-pixel gap to each direction to join the borders.

Here's the codes:

```css
:root {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

*[full-height] {
  height: 100%;
}

*[fill] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  --dimension: 50px;
  --outreach: 32px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid: var(--outreach) var(--dimension) var(--outreach) / var(--outreach) var(--dimension) var(--outreach);
}

.container * {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.direction {
  --b: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.357);
  border: var(--b) solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: separate;
  --r: 6px;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.direction.middle {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  border: hidden;
}

.direction.up {
  margin-bottom: var(--b);
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  border-bottom: hidden;
  border-radius: var(--r) var(--r) 0 0;
  background-size: 36%;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48c3ZnIHdpZHRoPSI0OHB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQ4cHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIj4gPHBvbHlnb24gaWQ9InVwIiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIiBwb2ludHM9IjEyIDAgMjQgMTggMCAxOCI+PC9wb2x5Z29uPjwvc3ZnPg==);
}

.direction.down {
  margin-top: var(--b);
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 var(--r) var(--r);
}

.direction.left {
  margin-right: var(--b);
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: var(--r) 0 0 var(--r);
}

.direction.right {
  margin-left: var(--b);
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 var(--r) var(--r) 0;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48c3ZnIHdpZHRoPSI0OHB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQ4cHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIj48cG9seWdvbiBpZD0icmlnaHQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDkwIDEyIDEyKSIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgcG9pbnRzPSIxMiwwIDI0LDE4IDAsMTgiPjwvcG9seWdvbj48L3N2Zz4=);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div fill class="direction middle"></div>
  <div fill class="direction up"></div>
  <div fill class="direction down"></div>
  <div fill class="direction left"></div>
  <div fill class="direction right"></div>
</div>
```

> Environment: Microsoft Edge 113.0.1774.35 (arm64, macOS 13)